# How can i duplicate and place new stackpanels on buttonpress at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a stack panel in XAML which currently has a column of 7 textboxes.  I have a button on my form which i would like to duplicate the current stackpanel and place a new instance of it next to the existing one every time it is clicked.
Is this possible?

My Try:

```
var mynewstackpanel = new StackPanel(); 
var entry1 = new TextBox(); 
var entry2 = new TextBox(); 
entry1.Name = "newbox1"; 
entry1.Text= "newboxtext1";
entry2.Name = "newbox2"; 
entry2.Text = "newboxtext2"; 
mynewstackpanel.Children.Add(entry1); 
mynewstackpanel.Children.Add(entry2);
```

Comment: Definitely possible, but have you tried anything?

Comment: been googling like mad but cant see anything about duplicating one. was happy to create one in code, but cant get the code to output to my form (im a newbie,so likely missing something simple).  
            var mynewstackpanel = new StackPanel();

            var entry1 = new TextBox();
            var entry2 = new TextBox();

            entry1.Name = "newbox1";
            entry1.Text= "newboxtext1";
            entry2.Name = "newbox2";
            entry2.Text = "newboxtext2";
            mynewstackpanel.Children.Add(entry1);
            mynewstackpanel.Children.Add(entry2);

Comment: sorry - i have no idea why my post above loses all its formatting :(

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of writing a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ListBox and DataTemplate for this case. You Add items to the ListBox Horizontally using ItemsPanel and define a ItemsPanelTemplate. Refer below code.

```
<StackPanel>
       <ListBox x:Name="items">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                        <TextBox Width="35" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Add Content" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<string> lst;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lst = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.ItemsSource = lst;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lst.Add("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ayyappan - many thanks, i think this is almost it.  However, if i have 2 stackboxes sitting next to each other and i want to replicate both of these on a button press at the same time, how would i add that to this?  Also - it creates a stackpanel which takes up the whole width of my form, other than just the width ive set (which i see correctly when using the stackpanel on its own). Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the TextBoxes layout which you want to repeat

Comment: Hey Ayyappan - basicially i have 2 stackpanels, both with 7 textboxes and i want to display them side by side.  The width of the textboxes in the stackpanel on the left is (as youve shown above) 100, and the width of the textboxes in the second stackpanel is 35.   When i click my button, i want to add both stackpanels/sets of textboxes and keep building across the page horizontally

Comment: That did it.  Thank you so much!  Im going to read through the code and make sure i understand it all

Answer (score 2):

You want to create the controls dynamically actually. So WPF has got a great support for that.

You can do this using ItemsControl and changing its ItemTemplate to have whatever controls you want to generate. Precisely this is what you want to do:

1. Take an ItemsControl in the xaml and bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.
2. Change ItemsControl's ItemTemplate to have your StackPanel you are talking about.
3. Now in button click command, just keep adding data to your ObservableCollection.

This is a rough idea of how you can achieve it. You will have to code yourself.

P.S. Please mark as answered if you feel I answered it.